# Use map object as function input

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a function that calculates the variance of an iterator of floats, I would like to be able to call this function on an iterator after using the map method to transform it.

```
use num::Float;

fn compute_var_iter<'a, I, T>(vals: I) -> T
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    T: 'a + Float + std::ops::AddAssign,
{
    // online variance function
    // Var = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 
    // corrects for 1/n -> 1/(n-1)

    let mut x = T::zero();
    let mut xsquare = T::zero();
    let mut len = T::zero();

    for &val in vals {
        x += val;
        xsquare += val * val;
        len += T::one();
    }

    ((xsquare / len) - (x / len) * (x / len)) / (len - T::one()) * len
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<f64> = (1..100001).map(|i| i as f64).collect();
    let b: Vec<f64> = (0..100000).map(|i| i as f64).collect();

    dbg!(compute_var_iter(&mut a.iter())); // this works
    dbg!(compute_var_iter(a.iter().zip(b).map(|(x, y)| x * y))); // this does not work
}
```

Is there a performant way to get the map output back to an iterator or to make the function take the map object as an input so that we can avoid having to .collect() and keep the execution lazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the iterator objects directly without collect:

```rust
use num::Float;

fn compute_var_iter<I, T>(vals: I) -> T
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Float + std::ops::AddAssign,
{
    // online variance function
    // Var = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 
    // corrects for 1/n -> 1/(n-1)

    let mut x = T::zero();
    let mut xsquare = T::zero();
    let mut len = T::zero();

    for val in vals {
        x += val;
        xsquare += val * val;
        len += T::one();
    }

    ((xsquare / len) - (x / len) * (x / len)) / (len - T::one()) * len
}

fn main() {
    let a = (1..100001).map(|i| i as f64);
    let b = (0..100000).map(|i| i as f64);
    let c: Vec<f64> = (0..10000).map(|i| i as f64).collect();

    dbg!(compute_var_iter(a.clone())); // this works
    dbg!(compute_var_iter(c.iter().map(|i| *i))); // this works
    dbg!(compute_var_iter(a.zip(b).map(|(x, y)| x * y))); 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f9446bff34495286968154001b7f8c7)

Notice that you would need to clone the iterator if you intend to use it several times. Also you do not really need to use references since numbers are usually `Copy` and the cost is the same as creating the references itself.

Comment: You might want an indirection in case you want to process data from a collection without transfering ownership of that data though e.g. if `a` is a vec instead of a cheaply clonable iterator.

Comment: @Masklinn, yeah, you can always use the collection, dereferencing the items too. Not sure if it can be done it so it would work for both.

Comment: Maybe something like `I: Iterator<Item=R>, R: AsRef<T>` something like that?

Comment: @Masklinn, but the problem is that the traits in num, Float in this case, is not implemented for &Float iirc, so at the end you have to dereference it hence copying the underlaying data. And then it wouldnt work for plain iterators `T` since `AsRef<T>` is not implemented for `T`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dbb9989d3dbba6bb06b230119d161d4d